# JasperReports optional dependencies

Tags: java, jasper-reports

The JasperReports library defines a set of optional dependencies (POI, Xalan, Ant, Jackson, ...)

I could not find anything in the documentation that clearly indicates when to add which dependency (one or more JAR files).

I am searching for a document that would indicates which dependency is related to which features.

Does such a documents exists ?

Comment: You can look at *pom.xml* file

Comment: I've got a similar issue myself. Jasper Reports isn't loading the Apache POI dependency, but as I don't use POI explicitly, I was hoping there was a way to tell Jasper Reports to include it, but I cannot find any way of doing this. So I just end up including the dependency myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the **JasperReports** class library already includes the required **JAR** files.

Here some of the dependencies:

> - **iText** is a **PDF** generation and manipulation library. It also has the ability to generate and manupulate **RTF**, **XML**, and
>     **HTML** documents. **JasperReports** takes advantage of **iText** for exporting reports to **PDF** and **RTF**.
> - **JFreeChart** is a **Java** library for producing various charts, including pie charts, bar charts, line and area charts, and the like.
>     **JasperReports** takes advantage of **JFreeChart** to implement its built-in charting functionality.
> - **Jakarta POI** is a **Java** class library to create and manipulate various **Microsoft Office** formats based on **Microsoft's OLE 2
>     Compound Document** format. **JasperReports** takes advantage of
>     **Jakarta POI** for exporting reports to **XLS** (**Microsoft Excel**) format.
> - **JAXP** refers to the **Java API** for parsing and transforming **XML** documents. It is used by **JasperReports** to parse **XML** files.
> - **Jakarta Commons**: Jakarta Commons is a collection of Java libraries providing a large number of reusable components.
>     JasperReports takes advantage of the Digester, BeanUtils, and Logging
>     components of Jakarta Commons to complement JAXP for XML parsing.

<sup>Source: "JasperReports for Java Developers" by David R. Heffelfinger</sup>